# Initialize elements after expanding row with bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am creating a table with bootstrap-table.com. Some rows are expandable with [expand-row.bs.table](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/#onexpandrow). Unfortunately I am unable to manipulate any element in the expanded area after expanding them.

For example I tried to set the value of the input field:

```
$table.on('expand-row.bs.table', function(e, index, row, $detail) {
    var res = $("#desc" + index).html();
    $detail.html(res);
    // set input text
    $('#inputTimetator1').val('input test text');
});
```

Later I wanted to initialize some select2 in the hidden areas when expanding them. Any idea on how to initialize these items?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nickkkk/f0eghaq1/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was not able to change the `$detail` dom element because you were trying to set it with multiple dom elements with no parent or root one, so in order to make the expandible row manipulated you have to fill it with dom elements wrapped inside one root dom element like div or span
and make sure to set only the first input you find inside the expandible row you have changed

just change your code to this and it will work just fine

```
$table.on('expand-row.bs.table', function(e, index, row, $detail) {
    var res = $("#desc" + index).html();
    $detail.html('<div>' + res + '</div>');
    $detail.find('input').val('input test text');
});
```

and here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohammad408/ertx6g9n/) link for it.